# How can I find the highest elements of an Array in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, element

Can someone please explain how one would get the highest elements of an array in Swift 2.2?

For example lets say I have this code:

```
let myArray: [Int] = [2, 1, 6, 3, 5 ,7, 11]
```

How would i retrieve the 3 highest values of that array?
In this case I'd want the numbers 6, 7 and 11.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are they always sorted like that?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils no they could be in any order.

Comment: A general approach to this task is to sort the sequence (in the given example they are already sorted) and take the first/last n-items. In some cases it may be beneficial to avoid the sort - really depends on the details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find the **3 highest** items, sort the array and take the last 3 items using `suffix`:

```
let myArray = [2, 1, 6, 3, 5 ,7, 11]
let highest3 = myArray.sort().suffix(3)
print(highest3)  // [6, 7, 11]
```

For the **3 lowest** items, use `prefix`:

```
let lowest3 = myArray.sort().prefix(3)
print(lowest3)  // [1, 2, 3]
```

`prefix` and `suffix` have the added advantage that they do not crash if your array has fewer than 3 items.  An array with 2 items for instance would just return those two items if you asked for `.suffix(3)`.

Answer (score -1):

```
let highestNumber = myArray.maxElement()
```

[Shown in playground](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USq9l.png)

Edit: Sorry, didn't read the full question, this method only retrieves the one highest value, here is a reconfigured version that should work

```
let myArray: [Int] = [2, 1, 6, 3, 5 ,7, 11, 4, 12, 5]
var myArray2 = myArray
var highestNumbers: [Int] = []

while highestNumbers.count < 3 {
    highestNumbers.append(myArray2.maxElement()!)
    myArray2.removeAtIndex(myArray2.indexOf(myArray2.maxElement()!)!)
    print(highestNumbers)
}
```

[Shown again in playground](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BU8fn.png)

Comment: The solution (I mean the second part) is not the most essential, however is the **fasted** by a computational point of view. Infact while the other answers do require a sorting with time `O(n log n)`, this code only requires time `O(n * k)` time where `k` is the number of elements in the solution. I think the users who downvoted should explain the reason.

Comment: The downvote came before I realized I read the question wrong and added a working solution to find three results